# Is there a way to stop my helmet from destroying my skin in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently purchased a cool skin in minecraft. However, the skin has a head covering that, like many modern skins, has extensions on it. When I put on a helmet, these extensions are deleted, leaving my character's face as a weird flat grey blob beneath the helmet. I tried downloading a texture pack that makes armor invisible, but this just made it so you couldn't see the armor, it didn't prevent the sticking-out parts of the skin from being flattened off when the helmet is equipped. Is there ANY way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to fix this. If you go into the Vanilla Resource Pack and find the "attachables" folder, there are a lot of armor .json files. Make a new resource pack with this folder and the .player.json files of the items you want to affect your skin differently (in this case every helmet file). To prevent the 3D aspects of your skin from being deleted, all you need to do is edit your versions of the .json files to change this line of code from this:

```
"scripts": {
    "parent_setup": "variable.helmet_layer_visible = 0.0;"
```

To this:

```
"scripts": {
    "parent_setup": "variable.helmet_layer_visible = 1.0;"
```

Then get your new resource pack set up with a manifest.json and a pack icon, put it into the resource packs folder, go into the game and activate it, and you should be good to go.

...basically all I had to do is change a zero to a one. Lol. So far it doesn't seem to have broken anything else. Although you may want to use this in conjunction with a mod that makes armor invisible (or build it into the same mod), because some skins look pretty odd sticking out through the armor!